# how to filter pandas dataframes by multiple columns and conditions

Tags: python, pandas, filter, conditional-statements, contains

I have the following set of data:

[image]

I am trying to filter the results using the following:

```
df = df.loc[
    (df['Left In Stock']>10) 
    & (df['Price (£)']>=10) 
    & (df['Weight(g)']<=700) 
    & ~(
        df['Title'].str.contains('the raven|on the') 
        & df['Colour']=='White'
    )
]
```

I am trying to achieve the following results:

[image]

In short I am trying to apply 4 conditions to filter the database by first removing all rows that have stock less than 10 with price greater than or equal to £10. Exclude rows with weight over 700g and finally if the title contains the phrase "the raven" or "on the" AND colour is white to only exclude those rows.

If the title contains the phrase "the raven" or "on the" AND colour as anything but white, then those rows should still be included in the result.

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 301, in na_logical_op
    result = op(x, y)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\AutoTrader.py", line 189, in <module>
    df = df.loc[(df['Left In Stock']>10) & (df['Price (£)']>=10) & (df['Weight(g)']<=700) & ~(df['Title'].str.contains('the raven|on the') & df['Colour']=='White')]
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 70, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 70, in __and__
    return self._logical_method(other, operator.and_)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 5634, in _logical_method
    res_values = ops.logical_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 391, in logical_op
    res_values = na_logical_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 308, in na_logical_op
    result = libops.vec_binop(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), op)
  File "pandas\_libs\ops.pyx", line 252, in pandas._libs.ops.vec_binop
  File "pandas\_libs\ops.pyx", line 245, in pandas._libs.ops.vec_binop
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: are you getting an error or unexpected results? in short, what is the problem you are having with your code? also please copy the sample data in the question as text or code (not as image)

Comment: The Following statement works without any issue: 

df = df.loc[(df['Left In Stock']>10) & (df['Price (£)']>=10) & (df['Weight']<=700)]

However I also want to exclude rows which have a particular string in the title if the colour is white.

Comment: place each of your conditions within parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.gt() .le() .ne() .eq() etc.` can save a lot of headache when it comes to getting all your `()` correct. As well as formatting your code across multiple lines for clarity:

```
mask = (df['Left In Stock'].gt(10)
        & df['Price (£)'].ge(10)
        & df['Weight(g)'].le(700)
        & ~(df['Title'].str.contains('the raven|on the')
            & df['Colour'].eq('White')))

out = df.loc[mask]
```